# Protege Pellet Reasoner with error but not HermiT

Tags: owl, protege, pellet

I used the HermiT Reasoner for some time but wanted to try the Pellet Reasoner. But Pellet throws an error on startup. The Log is not helpful:

```
  ERROR  22:28:49  An error occurred during reasoning: null.
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
    at com.clarkparsia.pellet.datatypes.types.text.RestrictedTextDatatype.applyConstrainingFacet(RestrictedTextDatatype.java:93) ~[na:na]
    at com.clarkparsia.pellet.datatypes.DatatypeReasonerImpl.getDataRange(DatatypeReasonerImpl.java:440) ~[na:na]
    at com.clarkparsia.pellet.datatypes.DatatypeReasonerImpl.containedIn(DatatypeReasonerImpl.java:303) ~[na:na]
    at com.clarkparsia.pellet.datatypes.DatatypeReasonerImpl.isSatisfiable(DatatypeReasonerImpl.java:704) ~[na:na]
    at com.clarkparsia.pellet.datatypes.DatatypeReasonerImpl.isSatisfiable(DatatypeReasonerImpl.java:665) ~[na:na]
    at org.mindswap.pellet.Literal.checkClash(Literal.java:339) ~[na:na]
    at org.mindswap.pellet.Literal.addType(Literal.java:261) ~[na:na]
    at org.mindswap.pellet.tableau.completion.CompletionStrategy.addType(CompletionStrategy.java:438) ~[na:na]
    at com.clarkparsia.pellet.rules.ContinuousRulesStrategy.addType(ContinuousRulesStrategy.java:95) ~[na:na]
    at org.mindswap.pellet.tableau.completion.rule.AllValuesRule.applyAllValues(AllValuesRule.java:175) ~[na:na]
    at org.mindswap.pellet.tableau.completion.rule.SimpleAllValuesRule.applyAllValues(SimpleAllValuesRule.java:68) ~[na:na]
    at org.mindswap.pellet.tableau.completion.CompletionStrategy.addType(CompletionStrategy.java:469) ~[na:na]
    at com.clarkparsia.pellet.rules.ContinuousRulesStrategy.addType(ContinuousRulesStrategy.java:95) ~[na:na]
    at org.mindswap.pellet.tableau.completion.rule.UnfoldingRule.applyUnfoldingRule(UnfoldingRule.java:98) ~[na:na]
    at org.mindswap.pellet.tableau.completion.rule.UnfoldingRule.apply(UnfoldingRule.java:61) ~[na:na]
    at org.mindswap.pellet.tableau.completion.rule.AbstractTableauRule.apply(AbstractTableauRule.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at com.clarkparsia.pellet.rules.ContinuousRulesStrategy.complete(ContinuousRulesStrategy.java:311) ~[na:na]
    at org.mindswap.pellet.ABox.isConsistent(ABox.java:1423) ~[na:na]
    at org.mindswap.pellet.ABox.isConsistent(ABox.java:1260) ~[na:na]
    at org.mindswap.pellet.KnowledgeBase.consistency(KnowledgeBase.java:1987) ~[na:na]
    at org.mindswap.pellet.KnowledgeBase.isConsistent(KnowledgeBase.java:2061) ~[na:na]
    at org.mindswap.pellet.KnowledgeBase.ensureConsistency(KnowledgeBase.java:2075) ~[na:na]
    at org.mindswap.pellet.KnowledgeBase.classify(KnowledgeBase.java:2083) ~[na:na]
    at com.clarkparsia.pellet.owlapiv3.PelletReasoner.precomputeInferences(PelletReasoner.java:1067) ~[na:na]
    at org.protege.editor.owl.model.inference.OWLReasonerManagerImpl$ClassificationRunner.precompute(OWLReasonerManagerImpl.java:447) ~[na:na]
    at org.protege.editor.owl.model.inference.OWLReasonerManagerImpl$ClassificationRunner.run(OWLReasonerManagerImpl.java:388) ~[na:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
```

I think I missed the point to just go back and redo all changes.  So what can I do?

I don't Know why, but the reasoner does not like

```
PAT_GNAME only xsd:string[maxLength 30]
```

but

```
PAT_FAMSTAND only xsd:string[maxLength 2]
```

is okay.

I tried to use

```
PAT_GNAME only string[maxLength 30]
```

as mentioned in the [manchester](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-manchester-syntax/#datatypeRestriction) syntax but protege does not like it.

So either protege or pellet does not like it.

Conclusion: I had a problem with my testdata, since i found it withe the help of your comments everything is working fine. Both PAT_GNAME and PAT_FAMSTAND work properly. Thanks!

Comment: in your ontology there is most likely some datatype facet which isn't supported. Without seeing the ontology, impossible to give further support

Comment: There's a literal of string type (or string derived type) with unsupported facets applied to it.

Comment: okay so it is about: PAT_GNAME only xsd:string[maxLength 30]

Comment: I'm pretty sure your second axiom only works because it is a different property which is not used in the data - is this assumption correct? The reason for the error is that the validation of string literals against such a facet was simply not implemented, see https://github.com/stardog-union/pellet/blob/service/core/src/main/java/com/clarkparsia/pellet/datatypes/types/text/RestrictedTextDatatype.java#L90-L94

Comment: - indeed, this would be easy to fix if you're capable of Java programming. In the Pellet fork called Openllet this has been added already: https://github.com/Galigator/openllet/commits/integration/module-core/src/main/java/openllet/core/datatypes/types/text/RestrictedTextDatatype.java